# regex- get string in single quotes and get first number in parenthesis

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to get the first string that is in the text and the first number inside the parentheses. I don't need the  decimal points after it.

for example. I want to be able to get the bold italicized pieces from below with a regular expression, or if there is a simpler way to do this in ruby I'm open to that.

'***esxi_devtest_sata_01***'(free)=1423749.73 MB (***69***.52%)

My data is added below in case that helps.

```
 'esxi_devtest_sata_01'(free)=1423749.73 MB (69.52%) 
 'gdw_tst_redo05'(free)=297022.46 MB (78.29%) 
 'olap_swapfile'(free)=511973.11 MB (99.99%) 
 'gdw_tst_redo01'(free)=438087.98 MB (35.32%) 
 'esxi_olap_sas10k_01'(free)=901445.18 MB (32.60%) 
 'gdw_tst_data03'(free)=2436425.63 MB (34.16%) 
 'gdw_prd_data01'(free)=677821.22 MB (55.74%) 
 'gdw_prd_data04'(free)=254195.75 MB (29.03%) 
 'esxi_dblnxtst_sas10k_02'(free)=1724435.82 MB (96.74%) 
 'gdw_sata_data01'(free)=333663.94 MB (16.75%) 
 'gdw_tst_data07'(free)=625859.36 MB (27.97%) 
 'gdw_tst_redo07'(free)=153516.10 MB (54.42%) 
 'gdw_sata_data03'(free)=64317.16 MB (2.94%) 
 'gdw_sata_data04'(free)=171041.27 MB (8.59%)
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I don't really know regex at all. I tried the following  (/['A-Z'][^()]\w+/) hopeing to get the first portion - the 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I suppose you could achieve this:

```
result = text.match(/'([^']+)'.*\((\d+)/)
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/351397)